# API not working after giving authentication permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created an API to list the employees and applied authentication permission.
when I tried to load the page it shows a login page. After giving the  login credentials it shows a page not found error. Before the authentication the url's was working perfectly.

views.py

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser



class EmpListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmpModelSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['Ename', 'Position']
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/employee/', EmpListView.as_view(), name='emp-list'),]
```

Comment: _After giving the login credentials it shows a page not found error_ What url is it trying to load?

Comment: admin/employee/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I have given `admin/employee/` which lead to the 404 error. I have changed my url pattern as `employee/`.
Removing the `admin/` resolved the problem.